# What is the problem in this bst code ? When i enter the first node's data it gives me error and doesn't move on

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
     in this code node structure and insertion and inorder traversal code has 
    been written and whenever i compile this code it doesn't give me any error 
    or exception but when i run this code this only takes one input and then 
    show me that there is an error thats why it can not be continued further. 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node //structure for node

{

    int data;

    node *left;

    node *right;

};
     in this code node structure and insertion and inorder traversal code has 
    been written and whenever i compile this code it doesn't give me any error 
    or exception but when i run this code this only takes one input and then 
    show me that there is an error thats why it can not be continued further.
class bst

{

    public:

        node *root;

        node *temp;

        int key;

        bst()

        {

            root = temp = NULL;

            key = 0;

        }

        bst insertion(node*); 
Kindly oversee this function and tell me 
what is the error in this function and the function of inorder

        bst inorder(node*);

};

bst bst::insertion(node *temp) this function is for insertion

{

    if(root==NULL) check if the root is null

    {

        cout<<"Enter Root Ki info:"<<endl;

        cin>>root->data;

        root->left = root->right = NULL;

    you must say that i should return over here but the return function 
    can not be available here and i am unable to correct this one.

    }

    cout<<"Enter Data:"<<endl;

    cin>>key;

    if(key>root->data) check if key is greater than the root's data

    {

        temp->right = new node;  it makes new node from right

        temp->right->data= key;

        temp->right->left = NULL;

        temp->right->right = NULL;
if i return temp over here it says me that this can not be done because of the node * pointer can not be converted into bst pointer and etc.
    }

    else if(key<root->data)  check if key is below than the root'data

    {

        temp->left = new node;

        temp->left->data = key;

        temp->left->left = NULL;

        temp->left->right = NULL;

    }
```

}

bst bst::inorder(node *temp) 
this function is used to show the node details in inorder scheme

{

```
    if(root==NULL)

    {

        cout<<"Nothing to be found"<<endl;

    }
     this is for inorder in which the the root element will be shown after the left nodes and at the end right nodes of the root will be shown and similarly post and preorder traversal can be done but this is not showing me any thing can you describe what will be the exact reason and i have tried to oversee all the elements by varying the pointer of struct in the main call but it doesn't make any difference
    inorder(temp->left);

    cout<<temp->data<<'\t';

    inorder(temp->right);
```

this is for inorder in which the the root element will be shown after the left nodes and at the end right nodes of the root will be shown and similarly post and preorder traversal can be done but this is not showing me any thing can you describe what will be the exact reason and i have tried to oversee all the elements by varying the pointer of struct in the main call but it doesn't make any difference
   }

this is for inorder in which the the root element will be shown after the left nodes and at the end right nodes of the root will be shown and similarly post and preorder traversal can be done but this is not showing me any thing can you describe what will be the exact reason and i have tried to oversee all the elements by varying the pointer of struct in the main call but it doesn't make any difference
   int main()

{

```
    bst b;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

    {

        b.insertion(b.root); error occurs when this is running



    }

    b.inorder(b.root);  it doesn't reach till this point

    system("Pause");
it is demanding more and more detail all is this what should i describe moe kindly tell me that also [enter link description here][1]
```

}

Comment: Please make the effort of formatting your question so it's readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but there's not very much that is right about this code.

The design is wrong. You should ask for the key in the main function, and then pass the key to the `insertion` method as a parameter. In doesn't make sense to pass a temporary node as a parameter. If `insertion` needs a temporary node then it should create one for itself.

Also `insertion` does not need to return a BST, it only needs to modify the BST pointed to by the `this` pointer. So `insertion` should look something like this

```
void bst::insertion(int key) {
    ...
}
```

And main should look something like this

```
int main()
{
    bst b;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter data";
        int key;
        cin >> key;
        b.insertion(key);
    }
    b.inorder();
}
```

Method `bst::inorder` has similar errors.

Also bst does not need member variables for a key and a temp node. So remove

```
int key;
node *temp;
```

from `class bst`. If you need these variables in a method then declare them in the method not in the class. The only thing the class needs is a pointer to the root.

The algorithm in `insertion` is wrong. Adding a node to a BST requires some kind of *loop*. You have to iterate through the tree until you get to a free slot, only then can you insert the node. Your `insertion` code has no loop, so it cannot be right.

Finally the reason that your code crashes is here

```
if(root==NULL)
{
    cout<<"Enter Root Ki info:"<<endl;
    cin>>root->data;
```

If root is NULL then `root->data` is an error and will likely crash your program.

There are too many problems with this code. I think you need to get a better idea of how to **design** classes before you try to code them. Sorry.

Comment: i have made the root==Null section correct and it is like this now

Comment: if(root==NULL)
{
root = new node;
cout<<"Enter Root Ki info:"<<endl;
cin>>root->data;
root->left = NULL;
root->right = NULL;
}
but problem is occuring that it is not taking input after enter data  and kindly elaborate what is the issue in inorder

Comment: can you please rewrite the inorder and right and left nodes making algorithm

Comment: void bst::insertion(int key)
{
if(root==NULL)
{
root = new node;
root->data = key;
root->left = NULL;
root->right = NULL;
temp = root;
return;
}
if(key>root->data)
{ 
temp->right = new node;
temp->right->data = key;
temp->right->left = NULL;
temp->right->right = NULL;
return;  
}
else if(key<root->data)
{
temp->left = new node;
temp->left->data = key;
temp->left->left = NULL;
temp->left->right = NULL;
return;
}
}
void bst::inorder(node *temp)
{
if(root==NULL)
{
return;
}
inorder(temp->left);
cout<<temp->data<<'\t';
inorder(temp->right);
}

Comment: New code is looking a lot better, but you still have a couple of problems I can see. In `inorder` it should start `if (temp == NULL) return;` not if `if (root == NULL) return;`. Your insertion code is still wrong because it still needs a loop. Think about this, suppose you've added three items, a root, one to the left of the root, and one to the right of the root. What is your code going to do if you add a fourth item?

Answer (score 0):

//this is the final code and it is the answer for the whole code that it executes correctly and gives right answer always as it should be
    #include 
    using namespace std;
    struct node
    {
        node *left;
        node *right;
        int data;
    };
    class bst 
    {
        public:
        node *root;
        node *temp;
        bst()
        {
            temp = root = NULL;

```
    }
    void insertion(node*,int key);
    void inorder(node *);
};
void bst::insertion(node *temp,int key)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = key;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        root = temp;
        return;
    }
     else if(key<root->data)
    {
        if(temp->left!=NULL)
        {
        insertion(temp->left,key);
        return;
        }
        else
        {
         temp->left = new node;
         temp->left->data = key;
         temp->left->left = NULL;
         temp->left->right = NULL;
         return;
        }
     }
     else if(key>root->data)
    {
        if(temp->right!=NULL)
        {
            insertion(temp->right,key);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        temp->right = new node;
        temp->right->data = key;
        temp->right->left = NULL;
        temp->right->right = NULL;
        return;
        }
    }

}
void bst::inorder(node *temp)
{

    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(temp->left!=NULL)
    inorder(temp->left);
    cout<<temp->data<<'\t';
    if(temp->right!=NULL)
    inorder(temp->right);
}

int main()
{
    bst b;
    int choice;
    char ch;
    char c;

    do{
        cout<<"enter 1 for insertion and 2 to show BST and 3 to delete node: "<<endl;
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case'1':
                cout<<"enter no you want to insert in bst: "<<endl;
                cin>>choice;

                b.insertion(b.root,choice);
                break;
            case'2':
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"The data in BST: "<<endl;
                b.inorder(b.root);
                break;
        }

        cout<<"press y or Y for another insertion: "<<endl;
        cin>>c;
    }while(c == 'y' || c == 'Y' );
}
```

Comment: `temp` is pointless as an argument to `insertion`. It can just be a local pointer.  Nor do you need to do insertion recursively. [See it live](https://ideone.com/tapACz). That's what John was trying to tell you in his answer.